# My router (tp link) connected to cat5e cable but not connecting with 6e?

Tags: networking, router

after i reset my router, my laptop and pc are finely conntected to my router tp-link-archer-c60 with "short cat 5e cable"  but when im using cat6e long cable instead of 5e, arent connecting not even showing light...?

1. is tp link archer c60 router isnt capable of handling the speed of cat6e cable ?

the technician said "my router works fine with cat6e, not yours, so issue is with your router"
plz help me,

EDITING: crimping everything is done by technician, the wire is "24awg 6e cable outdoor" my wire long "20 meters"

Comment: Update the firmware (since you reset it)

Comment: ok sir, i dont know how to do it, i'll google it.

Comment: You need the router setup page. Google should help you. You did not provide details.

Comment: CAT 6E ???? That doesn't exist. It's probably CAT 6A. But anyway, if it works with 5E it will work with CAT 6 or CAT 6A. Cat 6 is a better quality cable than 5E. You say "long cable"... How long?
And how is this CAT 6 cable made? Did you buy it with connectors already attached or did you attach the connectors yourself? If the latter you probably did that wrong.
Please add that additional information to your question. (Use the edit button under the question. to update it.)

Comment: If you can, verify/test the cat 6e cable (w/ a cable tester, or use a different computer & router/switch/etc) and also visually inspect to see if the RJ45 jacks are terminated properly, or test with a 2nd cat 6e cable if you have one.  How long of a cable run are you working with?  A cat 5e can usually be run a few hundred feet before problems start to surface; the environment can have an impact (proximity to electrical wiring, noise, etc) sometimes.  If you're using a modern NIC and OS, it's unlikely any interface settings need to be changed from their defaults.  Is the NIC driver up to date?

Comment: on ur  advice, just upgraded it, but it still  "my laptop didnt showed light"

Comment: Tonny - Some cables are marketed as "6e" but I don't think 6e is an official standard.  The notion of an "enhanced" cat 6 cable gives people the idea that it's similar to the degree of enhancement offered in cat 5e (vs cat 5) --  which it isn't - not even close.

Comment: the wire has a coting it says "24awg 6e cable outdoor"

Comment: ya ive updated the each and every drivers , ive dual os  windows 10 and win 7" with up-to-date

Comment: Since your router's ports are 100mbps, consider using a long cat 5e instead.  If you're eventually going to run this network cable through walls/outside and/or you're going to introduce keystone jacks at some point, get a different cat 6/6a cable to test with before proceeding.

Comment: ok sir, thats what i thought to do,  thanks a lot.